# Need some guidance on setting up slideshow program on raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

So I'm trying to create a slideshow that displays both the weather and time for a front office TV and I found a program on github that does just that. Im currently using the feh program to just cycle through images I downloaded onto a flash drive but I want to add the weather and time although I'm not sure how to use this program to do so.

https://github.com/andrewdelph/python-slideshow-with-time-and-weather

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Wish I could leave this in a comment, but I'm still too new.
However I'm not sure you are in the right place. Are you looking for instructions for running a python program on a raspberry pi? Not trying to make your own? Because we are here to answer questions on how to program. Assuming you have code to review, and give suggestions for. Not to teach the basics of running a program.

That said straight from the github you supplied are the instructions. I took a little time to make them a little more newbie friendly.

Install python 2.7; (should be preinstalled on raspbian)
`sudo apt install python`

pip install pyowm
`sudo pip install pyowm`
Fill images folder with images you wish to display.
Then change location to desired City
inside the ss.py change 
`observation = owm.weather_at_place('Ottawa,CA')`
to the loation you want then run
`sudo python ss.py`

Comment: Do I set the location of the images folder after 'file_list'?

Comment: You shouldn't need to modify anything to get image to work. Looking at the github it looks like it should have added a directory when you downloaded it called pictures. That should be located in the same directory as ss.py The directory should already have images in it. You would want to remove them then add images you want to use.

Comment: I keep getting this error `python: can't open file 'ss.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory` on my raspberry pi and I get this error on my mac `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'ss.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
mac:~ michael$ python`

Comment: You might need to add the directory to the command, or CD to the location.
For instance if your on a raspberry pi, and you are logged in as the user pi.
Assuming you installed it using the git clone command.
```sudo git clone https://github.com/andrewdelph/python-slideshow-with-time-and-weather
```
you should be able to run it with.
```sudo python /home/pi/python-slideshow-with-time-and-weather/ss.py```
or
```cd /home/pi/python-slideshow-with-time-and-weather/```
Then
```sudo python ss.py```

Comment: Were you successful in getting this to run on your raspberry pi?

Comment: I'm about to leave work. I'll install it now, and let you know tomorrow if I have any success.

Comment: Im doing a fresh install of Raspian and giving your commands a go again. I've been playing around with it and might have deleted something I shouldn't have.

Comment: After a fresh install and typing 1st `sudo git clone https://github.com/andrewdelph/python-slideshow-with-time-and-weather` and 2nd `sudo python /home/pi/python-slideshow-with-time-and-weather/ss.py` I get several lines of code starting with `Skipping: filename (NOT a supported image)` and then at the end I get

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/pi/python-slideshow-with-time-and-weather/ss.py", line 214, in <module> main(startdir=args.path) File "/home/pi/python-slideshow-with-time-and-weather/ss.py", line 216, in main timeFont = pygame.font.Font("indulta/Indulta-Semi-Serif-boldFFP.otf", 100) IOError: unable to read font file 'indulta/Indulta-Semi-Serif-boldFFP.otf `

Comment: Looks like the script isn't able to find the font files. In ss.py on lines 116-118. Assuming your username is pi change them to.
```timeFont = pygame.font.Font("/home/pi/python-slideshow-with-time-and-weather/indulta/Indulta-SemiSerif-boldFFP.otf", 100)
    dateFont = pygame.font.Font("/home/pi/python-slideshow-with-time-and-weather/indulta/Indulta-SemiSerif-boldFFP.otf", 60)
    weatherFont = pygame.font.Font("/home/pi/python-slideshow-with-time-and-weather/indulta/Indulta-SemiSerif-boldFFP.otf", 60)```

Comment: Will get back to you tomorrow, tried changing the directories but got other errors and forgot to write them down, the pi is at my work.

Comment: Late update but I got the script to run. Now I'm troubleshooting blown up images. Thanks for all your help.